# What's the best way to examine .js files?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Ok, so this is a really random question, but here we go.

Say as a student, you create the following file:

```js
const name = 'John'
console.log(name)
```

As a 'robot' teacher, you examine the file for the following checks:

- The variable 'name' has the type string
- console.log(name) is called, with the variable name as a parameter

The best comparison I can put this as, is [Codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/). The only requirement I have, is that it needs to be checked with Node.js and not some other language with a JS parser.

Comment: I'd patch `console.log` beforehand and then just run the code

Comment: You're looking for a **JavaScript static analysis** tool or library. Program static analysis is a very hard problem - especially for JavaScript where programs can use `eval` and take advantage of its type system to obfuscate real program logic.

Comment: You can use this to walk through javascript syntax https://github.com/acornjs/acorn